# How to divide all element in list at once :: DART

Tags: list, for-loop, dart, if-statement

```
_num.sort();
List<int> _answer = [];

for (int i = 1; i <= _num.last; i++) {
  // help me pls 
  if (_num % i == 0) {
  }
```

i'm trying to do Greatest common divisor code but i don't know how to check if int i can divide all items in the list at once and remainder == 0

- If there is a better way to do this please tell me, thank you

Comment: *i pass parameter as List

Comment: If you need to check if all the elements in the list can be divided by a number you can use: `final canBeDivided = list.every((e) => e % yourNumber == 0)`. The every method checks if all the elements pass the predicate.

Comment: Thank you so much!